# why isn't this well typed?

Tags: haskell

I'm writing a function to produce a set of all permutations of a string -- "foo" should return {"foo", "ofo", "oof"}. I've done this already in Clojure, so I know this approach is correct, but I figured I'd do it in Haskell for practice. Below is what I've got.

```
import qualified Data.Set as Set

substr :: String -> Int -> Int -> String
substr s start end = take (end - start) . drop start $ s

substrs :: String -> Set.Set (Char, String)
substrs s = let len = length s
            in foldl (\acc x -> Set.insert (s !! x, ((substr s 0 x)++(substr s (succ x) len))) acc) Set.empty [0..len-1]

-- not sure about the type
permute [] = Set.empty
permute s = Set.map recurFunc (substrs s)
  where recurFunc (c, s) = Set.map (c:) (permute s)

main :: IO ()
main = print $ permute "foo!"
```

This doesn't compile, of course, or I wouldn't be asking. I get:

```
permute.hs:12:21:
Couldn't match expected type `String'
            with actual type `Set.Set [Char]'
Expected type: (Char, String) -> String
  Actual type: (Char, String) -> Set.Set [Char]
In the first argument of `Set.map', namely `recurFunc'
In the expression: Set.map recurFunc (substrs s)
```

`Set.map` is declared as `(a -> b) -> Set a -> Set b`. As far as I can tell, `recurFunc` takes a set of `(Char, String)` pairs, and returns a set of strings. `substrs` returns a set of `(Char, String)` pairs. So how is this inconsistent?

Comment: I'd suggest starting out using a list-based version first, and then adjusting it to use a `Set` later on if you decide you really need it. Lists are less confusing (and anyway, `Set` isn't a great deal faster for small amounts of data like this).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just a quick note: `type String = [Char]`.

`Set.map` takes a normal function and maps it over a set. Since you have a `Set (Char, String)` and you want a `Set String`, this function should have the type `(Char, String) -> String`.

However, your `recurFunc` returns a *set* rather than just a string. That is, it has a type `(Char, String) -> Set String`. (I think the type is actually a bit more general, but that isn't important.) So when you map it over a set, you get a set of sets: something like `Set (Set String)`.

This is what your error says in a slightly oblique way: it expected a `Set String` but got a `Set (Set String)`. However, since the error is about `recurFunc`, it only tells you about the problem with the function: `Set String` should just be `String`.

Hopefully that gives you enough information to fix your error.

Answer (score 1):

Using the fact that `String`s are simply lists of `Char`s you could quickly write:

```
import Data.List

permute = Eq a => [a] -> [[a]]
permute = nub . permutations
```

The predefined `permutations` actually makes all the job you want and `nub` simply deletes duplicates.

Note that this approach is not very effective ( *O(n^2)* ) and should only be used with a small amount of data!